# yarn install skips packages on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, yarnpkg

When run manually, `yarn install` works without a hitch.
When run from Jenkins, however, one package is simply missing! Even when run after a manual execution. I only run a single instance of `yarn` each time.

In both cases (manual and Jenkins) I use the same working directory and the same user. The missing package is `ng`, and it's a dependency of `@angular` (`yarn install` creates more `package.json` files in nested folders).

Any ideas what could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I use `yarn install --check-files` as a workaround until I figure out why `yarn` deletes packages in the first place. If anyone has a better solution I'd like to hear it :)